# I am having trouble with my ruby game please

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a game for ruby but I keep getting the following error at `PlayerMove = $STDIN.gets.chomp`:

> dynamic constant assignment error

I tried changing the front of `$STDIN` to `STDIN` to `gets.chomp` and nothing seems to work.

```
$Health = 100
$OPHealth = 50
def fight
  def NumberN
    $RandomNumber = ran(0..30)
  end

  def Player
    print ">"
    PlayerMove = gets.chomp
    if PlayerMove.downcase == "attack"
      RandomNumber - OPHealth
      puts "You attach the Spider and do #{RandomNumber} Damage,\n he has #{OPHealth}"
    elsif OPHealth >= 0
      puts "The SPIDER IS DEAD"
      ENDGAME()
    elsif Health >= 0
      puts "Your dead GAMEOVER you abomination"
    else
      puts "You need to attack" 
      Player()
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

This particular issue will be with the case you're using: for variables, Ruby uses lower snake case.

Update your code's variables to use, for example: `player_move = gets.chomp` and this will resolve the error.

Using upper camel case as you are is reserved for classes and modules (with constants typically using upper case). (I'm sure I'm missing something here - let me know if anyone can correct me.)

Therefore, assigning values as you are is throwing the "dynamic constant assignment error" you mention.

Have a bit of a read up on this: global variables prefixed with `$` are also seldom seen. This [style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#naming) is quite a good resource for this.

That said, simply updating the variables won't fix this in its entirety - you'll need to look at the the scoping and structure of your code before this will work. When you run into another issue, see how you get on and if you can't fix it, pop it into another question.

Comment: @TheKWarrior did this help at all?